# If my condition fulfilled, I want to hide two button/link with together. How can I do it?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

This is my conditional code:-
**{user ? <button onClick={logout} style={{ color: "#182D36" }} className=' btn btn-light  fs-6 fw-bold'> Log Out < /button> : <Nav.Link as={Link} to='login' >Login</Nav.Link> }**

I also want to hide this Sign-Up link (**<Nav.Link as={Link} to='register' >Sign UP</Nav.Link>**) by the condition

Comment: Are your buttons in the same div or further away in the DOM tree?

Comment: Can you add code examples? It'll be easier to get answer if we can see your actual code.

Comment: @TusharShahi , same div

Comment: And code are better when you click Select all then the bracket on the top....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap them in the same div...

```
{user ? <button onClick={logout} style={{ color: "#182D36" }} className=' btn btn-light fs-6 fw-bold'> Log Out < /button> : <div><Nav.Link as={Link} to='login' >Login</Nav.Link>
<Nav.Link as={Link} to='register' >Sign UP</Nav.Link>
</div> }
```

Comment: Then you should mark this question as solved by this answer.... Make us gain points...

Answer (score 0):

just throw the signup into the condition as well...

```jsx
const content = user ? 
<button onClick={logout} style={{ color: "#182D36" }} className=' btn btn-light fs-6 fw-bold'> Log Out < /button> 
:
<>
<Nav.Link as={Link} to='login' >Login</Nav.Link> 
<Nav.Link as={Link} to='register' >Sign UP</Nav.Link>
</>

return (
  <>
    {content}
  </>
)
```